# Fetching list of users in a react drop down list from a spring boot controller

Tags: reactjs

I want to fetch list of users from my spring boot backend and populate them in my React drop down list. Then I want to use a toggle switch to lock/unlock users in my table.

Right now the backend is complete and I'm able to lock/unlock users from my backend. I've tested the endpoint using postman. Now I want to implement this feature using React js dropdown list and a toggle switch. I need the response as a json.

Postman endpoint :- POST request

```
{
    "username":"john@gmail.com",
    "accstatus":"NORMAL"
}
```

Response is a success message saying the operation is true.

React JS code :-

```
class DropDownUsers extends Component {
  state = {
    users : [],
    selectedUser : "",
    validationError : ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/acctstatus")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        let usersFromApi = data.map(user => {
          return {
            value : user,
            display : user
          }})
        this.setState({ users : [{value: '', display: '(Choose the user)'}].concat(usersFromApi)});
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select value={this.state.selectedUser}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({selectedUser: e.target.value})}
         >
         {this.state.users.map((user) => <option key={user.value} value={user.value}> {user.display}</option>)}
        </select>
        <div style={{color:'red',marginTop:'5px'}}>
          {this.state.validationError}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Once the user is selected from the dropdown list, the toggle switch should be able to lock/unlock the user in the database. Currently the dropdown list is not populating the list of users.

Comment: Could you add the response data? Any error in the console log?

Comment: The component will initially render empty drop down as the async request might take time. On your state update, it will re-render. Check if your state is updated? Can you confirm if the state has right value from react dev tools or debug?

Comment: The response from postman is :-
```
{
    "username":"john@gmail.com",
    "accstatus":"NORMAL",
    "success" : "true"
}
```
I'm getting a ```POST http://localhost:8080/aa/api/accountStatus net::ERR_ABORTED 415``` and CORS error. I've added the ```@CrossOrigin``` annotation in my spring backend.